# jQuery .noconflict with prototype not working in (you guessed it) IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, prototypejs, jquery

On my [new customer page](http://www.euroworker.no/user/checkout/), I have successfully implemented a jQuery show/hide toggle alongside a Prototype script using jQuery's .noconflict. (Thanks to all for answers!)

But as the world of the net is, IE's not playing ball.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(function() {
      $j("#button1").click(function() {
        $j("#show-hide").toggle("slow");
      });
   });​
</script>
```

As you all must know by now, I'm just newly coming to all this jQuery stuff, so I have no idea what could cause it.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** IE reports that:

Object does not support specified property or method: var

```
var $j = jQuery.noconflict();
```

So is this noConflict var not IE friendly?

Comment: Any change when you add ` type="text/javascript"` to the first `<script>` tag?

Comment: @David Murdoch: looks like some sort of templating instruction.

Comment: No change at all with the type, and yes, it's a smarty template, you have to put scripts inside `{literal}` tags or it breaks.

Comment: Well, someone with 2000+ rep should remove it. Its messing with SO code highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some weird character encoding thing was going on, apparently `});` at the end were registering as invalid characters. I re-typed it and now it's working fine :).